# Django TextField default value

Tags: python, django, django-models

In one of my tables I have a field `game_fen_when_leave = models.TextField()`. But it gives me an error "You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'game_fen_when_leave' to game without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows)". Is it necessary for this field to have a default value? I saw an [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/textfield-django-models/) without having a default.

Comment: You should elaborate further what did you do, is this a new model, do you have existing data how do you save data etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**
When creating a new model: No it is not
When adding it to an existing model: Yes it is

**A bit more on the topic:**
With the information given I guess your are about to add this new field to an existing table.

When adding a new non-nullable fields to an existing model you will need to provide a default value. This is because there might already be rows in that particular table and those would need a default value to populate this new field with. (I'm actually just repeating the error message here.)

*In the example that you are referring:*
The model is new and there cannot be existing rows that would need to be populated with default values. Therefore default value for the TextField is not needed.

*Couple of possibilities*

- Remove and create the model from scratch: If you remove the table by migrations and create it again as a completely new table. You don't have to provide a default value as there cannot be existing rows.
- Add a default value: Default value could simply be an empty string and that probably is the way to go.

By default Django TextField is a non-nullable yes. You have the power to change that, but it is not advised to do so:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#null

> If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible
> values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string.